# PHP Redirect to self

Tags: php

So I'm creating a PHP config file that's included on every page.  In it, it'll check the user's access level and if it is a certain value, it'll redirect the user to a certain page.  For this access level, they only have access to one page so when testing this, I'm redirecting the user to the same page their currently on.  When I look at network in the chrome dev tools, it shows the `GET` request cancelled.  Is this correct behavior?  Or should it be reloading the page?  Looks a bit like this:

```
<?php
//set globals
$contractedUser = 1;
$isContractor = false;
$dr = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

//Get the page user is trying to load
$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
$referrerPathArray = explode('\\',$backtrace[0]['file']);
$lastElementIndex = sizeof($referrerPathArray) - 1;
$referrerPage = $referrerPathArray[$lastElementIndex];

//Get user data
$user = User::getUser();
//validate user's login, redirect to login if not
if (!$user) {
    $page = 'http' . (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? '' : 's') . '://' .         $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location:$dr/Admin?r=" . $page);
    die();
}

if ($user->getAccess() == $contractedUser) {
    $isContractor = true;
    $pin = $user->getPin();
}
if ($isContractor && ($referrerPage != 'CreateMenuEntry.php' && $referrerPage != 'CreateMenu.php')){
    header("Location: $dr/Admin/CreateMenuEntry.php");
}
else{
    echo $dr.'/Admin/CreateMenuEntry';
    echo $referrerPage;
}
```

UPDATE:
Jeroen helped me figure out that my issue was using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in the header.  I changed it to `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "Admin/CreateMenuEntry.php"` and it is now working.

Comment: Could you please show the code you're using, so we can tell you what's correct and what's wrong, and guide you in the right direction. If you just wanna redirect you the same page, you can get that by $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: Well I'm not sure that they will always be on the CreateMenuEntry page so I wanted to make sure to redirect there explicitly.  What other code would you like to see?  I'm sure it's stepping into that if statement because if I change the value in header to google, it redirects there.  I just know it's cancelling when I set it to that page.

Comment: Glad to be of help.. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looked like a redirect loop, but then after our comments & follow up chat it became clear that the problem was with the redirect itself.

When you're doing a redirect with header("Location: ....."), you are telling the user's browser to go somewhere. So that needs to be a valid public URL, or a valid path relative to the document root.

Now, for a browser the document root will be http://www.example.com - so if you redirect to /info.php, the user will get redirected to http://www.example.com/info.php.

But for your server the document root means something else, it is the absolute path on the server. So let's say your site is in the default /var/www. If you redirect a user to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/info.php', you are then actually redirecting them to: http://www.example.com/var/www/info.php - which of course does not exist.

So, when you want to include a PHP file server side which is in the public folder, you could use e.g.: include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/info.php'). But when you tell  the browser to redirect, you must see it from the browser's point of view and use the public address (your URL) instead, or a path relative to the URL - so 'http://www.example.com/info.php' or '/info.php'

Comment: But if I'm on /Admin/CreateMenu and try to load /Admin/CreateCategory, the header should redirect to /Admin/CreateMenuEntry where it loads this config file and will see that I'm trying to load CreateMenuEntry and will allow me to load it.  I'll post all the code to show you what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, but you're saying the above file is included on every page, so it is also included in CreateMenuEntry.php. The referer will never be CreateMenuEntry.php or CreateMenu.php if you're coming from CreateCategory.php - so a redirect loop is then the result.

Comment: Oh so if I try to hit `Admin/CreateCategory`, it redirects to `/Admin/CreateMenuEntry.php`, and `debug_backtrace()` will still point to `/Admin/CreateCategory`?

How can I get around this?

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused here. `debug_backtrace()` will only show information about the current request. You can not use it to find out which page the user was on in the previous request. If your purpose is to find out if a user was on CreateMenuEntry BEFORE he/she can do anything on CreateCategory - you could check that with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (if this page == CreateCategory but previous page != CreateMenuEntry: redirect to CreateMenuEntry). It's not really a safe way though - anyone can fake the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] but in your current code that should work.

Comment: No I just used referer because it's similar to what HTTP_REFERER does.  What it actually references is the page the user was trying to load.  So if I hit a link to `CreateCategory.php` the config file is included at the top and has no idea that it's attatchd to `CreateCategory.php` so I use `debug_backtrace()` to let the config know.

Comment: And you have tested that when you're on 'CreateMenuEntry.php' the value of `$referrerPage` is 'CreateMenuEntry.php' as well? Also, you're redirecting using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. If your Admin folder is located in http:/www.example.com/Admin you should redirect to /Admin/CreateMenuEntry.php, not $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . Admin/CreateMenuEntry.php

Comment: Yes, I have the echo in the `else` condition at the very end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71623/discussion-between-jeroen-flamman-and-jarryd-goodman).